# Generate a breadcrumb trail with xsl from a node structure

Tags: xslt, libxml2, libxslt

I have difficulties to write a template that generates a breadcrumb trial out of a node structure. It is not working correctly up to now, there is some flaw in my thinking how it should walk the **item** path.

Consider the following page structure:

```
<!-- ===== SITE PAGE STRUCTURE ===================================== -->
<index>
   <item section="home" id="index"></item>
   <item section="service" id="index">
      <item id="content-management-systems">
         <item id="p1-1"/>
         <item id="p1-2"/>
         <item id="p1-3"/>
      </item>
      <item id="online-stores"></item>
      <item id="search-engines-and-ir"></item>
      <item id="web-applications"></item>
   </item>

   <item section="solutions" id="index">
      <item id="document-clustering"></item>
   </item>
   <item section="company" id="index">
      <item section="company" id="about"></item>
      <item section="company" id="philosophy" ></item>
      ...
   </item>
...
</item>
```

This site index represents a site-structure of xml content pages in its hierarchy (consider it to be a menu). It contains of *sections*, that represent the site sections just as *home, company, service, solutions*, etc. These sections can contain *sub-sections* with pages, or just regular content pages. A content page (its xml contents such as title, text content, etc) is identified by the @id attribute in the item tree. The @id attribute mainly is used to fetch the content of the entire page that will be rendered to html. 
The breadcrumb template uses the *item* node @id attribute to get the title of the page (which will be shown in the breadcrumb trail).

I try to implement the following template that *walks* the tree by checking the target section attribute @section and the target page attribute @id in the tree. I expect it to walk the axis down until the target item_target is found by comparing the ancestors @section attribute and the @id with $item_target of each node in that axis.

For example: Attribute *$item_section=service* and the page id *target item_target=p1-1* should now recursively "walk" to the *section* branch "**service**" (depth 1), check if the target page @id is found on this level. In this case it is not found, so it makes the next recurive call (via apply-templates) to the next *item* node level (in this case it would be **content-management-systems**, there the target item page p1-1 is found, so the trail process is finished:

The result should like this:

**home >> service >> content management systems >> p1-1**

But unfortunately it is not working correct, at least not in every case. Also maybe it can be solved more easily. I try to implement it as an recursive template that walks from the top (level 0) to the target page (item node) as a leaf.

```
    <!-- walk item path to generate a breadcrumb trail -->
    <xsl:template name="breadcrumb">
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$req-lg"/>
                <xsl:text>/home/index</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="'Home'"/>
        </a>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="$content/site/index" mode="Item-Path">
            <xsl:with-param name="item_section" select="'service'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="item_target" select="'search-engines-and-ir'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="0"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="Item-Path">
        <xsl:param name="item_section" />
        <xsl:param name="item_target" />
        <xsl:param name="depth" />
        <!--
        depth=<xsl:value-of select="$depth"/>
        count=<xsl:value-of select="count(./node())"/><br/>
-->
        <xsl:variable name="cur-id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cur-section" select="@section"/>
        <xsl:choose>    
            <xsl:when test="@id=$item_target">
                &gt;&gt;
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                                            <!-- req-lg: global langauge variable -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="$req-lg"/>
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$item_section"/>
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:if test="$depth = 2">
                            <xsl:value-of select="../@id"/>
                            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of 
                        select="$content/page[@id=$cur-id]/title"/>
                </a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:if test="ancestor-or-self::item/@section = $item_section and count(./node()) > 0">
                &gt;&gt;:
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                                            <!-- req-lg: global langauge variable -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="$req-lg"/>
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$item_section"/>
                        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:if test="$depth = 2">
                            <xsl:value-of select="../@id"/>
                            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of 
                        select="$content/page[@id=$cur-id and @section=$item_section]/title"/>
                </a>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="Item-Path">
            <xsl:with-param name="item_section" select="$item_section"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="item_target" select="$item_target"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:template>
```

So as the hardcoded parameters in the template **breadcrumb**, target section = 'service' and target page = 'search-engines-and-ir', I expect an output like

**home >> service >> search-engines-and-ir**

But the output is

**home >> service >> content-management-systems >> search-engines-and-ir**

which is obviously not correct.

Can anybody give me a hint how to correct this issue? It would be even more elegant to avoid that depth checking, but up to now I cannot think of a other way, I am sure there is a more elegant solution.

I work with XSLT 1.0 (libxml via PHP5).

Hope my question is clear enough, if not, please ask :-) Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: The question isn't clear at all. Please, edit and explain how the parent-child relation is represented in the source XML document. Also, please, explain what is given and what must be produced  in the terms of the *tree*.

Comment: @ Dimitre Novatchev: Sorry if my questions is unclear. I edited my questions and tried to be more exact, see the text between the xml tree and the xsl template code. Hope it is more clear what I try to achieve ...

Comment: In your input document, service is not a child of home. Shouldn't your expected output be simply...`service >> search-engines-and-ir` ?

Comment: Yes, for now *home* is hard-coded in the template *breadcrumb*. I might change the index item structure to be home as the parent though, so it would be walked as the first item node in the future. For now it is with all site sections on the first level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kNodeById" match="item" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>home</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="findPath">
   <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="'service'"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="'search-engines-and-ir'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="findPath">
  <xsl:param name="pStart"/>
  <xsl:param name="pEnd"/>

  <xsl:for-each select=
  "key('kNodeById', $pEnd)
       [ancestor::item[@section=$pStart]]
        [1]
         /ancestor-or-self::item
                [not(descendant::item[@section=$pStart])]
  ">

   <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat('>>', @id[not(../@section)], @section)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
home>>service>>search-engines-and-ir
```

**Do Note**:

1. This solution prints the breadcrumb from any node -- anywhere in the hierarchy to any of its descendent nodes -- anywhere in the hierarchy. More precisely, for the first `item` (in document order) with `id` attribute equal to `$pEnd`, the breadcrumb is generated from its inner-most ancestor whose `section` attribute is equal to `$pStart` -- to that `item` element.
2. This solution should be much more efficient than any solution using `//`, because we are using a key to locate efficiently the "end" `item` element.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution:**

Much shorter and easier -- an XPathe 2.0 single expression:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kNodeById" match="item" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "string-join(
       (
        'home',
       key('kNodeById', $pEnd)
          [ancestor::item[@section=$pStart]]
              [1]
                /ancestor-or-self::item
                [not(descendant::item[@section=$pStart])]
                       /(@id[not(../@section)], @section)[1]

        ),
      '>>'
        )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks for that. Actually I have never used the `key()` function yet. I modified the xslt 1.0 solution a little bit, I changed the *ancestor::item* to ancestor-or-self::item in the for-each loop to be able to also get the first level items of the tree (for example *service*, *solutions*, etc). With that the breadcrump works completely. Also I used that template (the technique) to generate the URL (the path part) of each crumb!

Comment: @AndreasW.Wylach, You are welcome. Keys are a very powerful feature of XSLT and it is worth it toget to know and use this feature. In case you are limited to XSLT 1.0, the most efficient method for grouping is by using keys (the Muenchian grouping method).

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the ancestor-or-self:: axis . This is easy to do without recursion. For example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html><body>
    <xsl:call-template name="bread-crumbs">
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="*/item" />
      <xsl:with-param name="section" select="'service'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="leaf" select="'p1-2'" />
    </xsl:call-template>  
  </body></html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="bread-crumbs">
  <xsl:param name="items" />
  <xsl:param name="section" />
  <xsl:param name="leaf" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($section,'&gt;&gt;')" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$items/self::item[@section=$section]//item[@id=$leaf]/
                        ancestor-or-self::item[not(@section)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;&gt;'" />
    </xsl:if>  
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...on your sample input yields...

```
<html>
  <body>service&gt;&gt;content-management-systems&gt;&gt;p1-2</body>
</html>
```

...which renders as...

```
service>>content-management-systems>>p1-2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it out and it is working. Dimitre provided a solution that I also could easily get the url (the href attribute) of the tree to add to the link of one bread crumb.